# How can I avoid memory allocation error for large vector?

Tags: rust, bioinformatics

I'm trying to solve the [shortest superstring problem on leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-the-shortest-superstring/) for an assigment. My code solves the problem fine for a small number of sequences,  but when trying to find a solution for about 50 1000-character long sequences, I get `memory allocation of 27021597764222976 bytes failed`.

I'm trying to implement a dynamic programing approach but the program crashes when creating big vector with:

```rust
let mut dp: Vec<Vec<String>> = vec![vec![String::new(); n]; 1 << n];
```

Is there a better way for handling this allocation? I'm wondering also if I just need more heap space or is just my machine.

The full function (which is based on a [Python solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-the-shortest-superstring/solutions/3525294/solution/) in fact):

```rust
fn shortest_superstring(sequences: Vec<String>) -> String {
    // Find the shortest superstring of a list of sequences
    //
    // # Arguments
    // * `sequences` - A vector of sequences
    //
    // # Returns
    // The shortest superstring of the sequences
    let n = sequences.len();
    // this hashmap will be populated with the minimum suffixes needed to concatenate each pair of sequences
    let mut suffix: HashMap<usize, HashMap<usize, String>> = HashMap::new();
    for i in 0..n {
        suffix.insert(i, HashMap::new());
        for j in 0..n {
            if i != j {
                // store the minimum suffix of sequence j that doesn't overlap with sequence i
                suffix.get_mut(&i).unwrap().insert(j, get_min_suffix(&sequences[i], &sequences[j]));
            } else {
                // if the sequences are the same, the minimum suffix is an empty string
                suffix.get_mut(&i).unwrap().insert(j, "".to_string());
            }
        }
    }

    // "table" to store the shortest superstring for each possible combination of sequences
    //
    println!("Pre alloc");
    let mut dp: Box<Vec<Vec<String>>> = Box::new(vec![vec![String::new(); n]; 1 << n]);
    //let mut dp: Vec<Vec<String>> = vec![vec![String::new(); n]; 1 << n];
    println!("Post alloc");
    // iterationg over all possible combinations of sequences

    for i in 1..1<<n {
        // indices included in the current combination
        let indexes: Vec<usize> = (0..n).filter(|&j| i & (1 << j) != 0).collect();
        for j in &indexes {
            // exclude the current sequence from the combination
            let i2 = i & !(1 << j); // combination without the j-th sequence
            // construct all possible superstrings for the current combination
            let mut strs: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
            // iterate over all possible sequences to be concatenated to the current combination
            for j2 in &indexes {
                // exclude the current sequence from the combination
                if j2 != j {
                    // `i2` is the combination without the j-th sequence
                    // `j2` is the sequence to be concatenated to the current combination
                    let mut s = dp[i2][*j2].clone();
                    // `suffix[j2][j]` is the minimum suffix of sequence `j2` that doesn't overlap with sequence `j`
                    s.push_str(&suffix[j2][j]);
                    strs.push(s);
                }
            }
            // store the shortest superstring for the current combination
            dp[i][*j] = if !strs.is_empty() {
                strs.into_iter().min_by_key(|s| s.len()).unwrap()
            // if the current combination only contains one sequence, the shortest superstring is that sequence
            } else {
                sequences[*j].to_string()
            };
        }
    }
    // return the shortest superstring for the combination of all sequences (last row of the table)
    dp[(1<<n) - 1].iter().min_by_key(|s| s.len()).unwrap().to_string()
}
```

Comment: 1<<50 is 1125.8 **terabytes** if you only allocate a single byte per element, but a vector is 24 bytes, so you attempt to allocate ~25 Petabytes, that's not going to happen, you'll need to look for another algorithm or datastructure.

Comment: If this is meant to use sparse allocations that won't work since for most types the standard library doesn't know the vecs don't need initialization. `Option<Box<T>>` is one of the exceptions (not guaranteed though). So you'd have to do unergonomic things with `Vec<Option<Box<str>>>` to get a sparsely allocatable vec of strings.
But really, iterating from `1..1<<n` is going to take a very long time for large `n` even with sparse allocations.... I doubt the python code is doing the same, assuming it's meant to scale at all. Perhaps you could link the python code you're trying to adapt.

Comment: Maybe a [HashMap](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html) would be a better data structure to use here?